# comint-input-ring-size ignored in shell-mode

Tags: comint, shell-mode

I am trying to change `comint-input-ring-size` in shell mode in Emacs. The `comint-input-file-name` is correctly set to `~/.bash_history` file which is a big file (around 5000 commands). However, if I set the `comint-input-ring-size` to 2000, I don't seem to be able to recall really old commands (which could be like 1000 commands away) with `comint-history-isearch-backward`.

Comment: I have the same question. Does anyone have any idea?